# disable campaigns google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I would like to **disable Campaign Tracking** on my GA property. I use Universal Analytics.

I've seen documentation here about method "_setCampaignTrack"

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiCampaignTracking#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setCampaignTrack

But I'm wondering how I implement it in GA Universal.

I've tried this code:

```
  ga('create', 'UA-37650441-9', 'auto');
  ga('set','_setCampaignTrack', false);
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

So I added

```
  ga('set','_setCampaignTrack', false);
```

But I'm not sure...please help me! ;)

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_setCampaigntrack was part of the older asynchronous code and I don't think that will work. AFAIIK there is no (documented) option to disable campaign tracking in Universal Analytics (looking at the [field reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference) confirms this).

However you could override the campaign name/medium/source-fields with the respective set field calls:

```
ga('set', 'campaignName', '(not set)');
ga('set', 'campaignSource', '(not set)');
ga('set', 'campaignMedium', '(not set)');
```

or do the same thing via filters in your view settings. That should give a similar result.

Comment: Yes Eike, thanks for your reply and as you confirmed I didn't find any documentated option to disable campaigns as well. Your solution is perfect for my objective, thanks again!